# Get the place_id of a city using google places autocomplete

Tags: google-places-api

I'm using an input field with google places autocomplete. I' ve set autocomplete to predict only cities but I'm stuggling to find a simple way to get the unique place_id of the selected city. I don't want to use it with google maps. I need it just to identify with a unique value the selected city.. Thanks in advance..

Here's my JS:

```
<script src="maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places"; type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function initialize() { 
  var options = { types: ['(cities)'] };
  var input = document.getElementById('searchCity');
  var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input,options);
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
```

And here's my PHP:

```
<form method="GET" action=<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>>
<input id="searchCity" type="text" size="50" 
  placeholder="Enter a City" autocomplete="on" name="city">
<br>
<?php if (!empty($_GET['city']) ) {
  echo $_GET['city'];
} else {
  echo "not set";
}
unset($_GET['city']); ?>
</form>
<!-- Here I would like to show the place_id of the selected city-->
</div>
```

Comment: Where are you stuck?  Assuming you're using the Places library for the Javascript Google Maps API, can't you just use the place_id of the result?

Comment: Yes I'm using the Places library for the Javascript Google Maps API.. I can't extract the place_id (probably from the json response). . My input field is in in a form that uses  action=<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?> and I just want to print it in the same page..

Comment: Can you share the code where you're handling the autocomplete results?  E.g. what does your place_changed event handler look like?

Comment: <script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
   function initialize() {
       var options = {
    types: ['(cities)'] };
     
  var input = document.getElementById('searchCity');
     var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input,options);
 
 }
    
   google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>

Comment: <form method="GET" action=<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>>
      <input id="searchCity" type="text" size="50" placeholder="Enter a City" autocomplete="on" name="city">
  <br>
  <?php 
  
  if (!empty($_GET['city']) ) {  echo $_GET['city'];} 
  else {echo "not set";}
  unset($_GET['city']);
  ?>
      
  </form>

   <!-- Here I would like to show the place_id of the selected city-->

 
   </div>

Comment: Thanks, I've submitted an edit to add that code to your question, and taken a go at writing an answer for it.

Answer (score 7):

You don't need PHP to display the place details.  You just need a Javascript event handler for `place_changed`.

E.g. add this code to your `initialize` function:

```js
google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() {
  var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
  var form = input.parentElement;
  form.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Place ID is " + place.place_id));
});
```

These samples from Google's docs contain complete examples of using the `place_changed` event.  They're worth looking at:

- https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete
- https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-placeid-finder